# Using an Arraylist of names to create jpanel rows in Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm trying to make a program that is able to read through an arraylist with shop names that can then be used to create the same Jpanel for each one. So in the below example the end would be the creation of a Row1 and Row2 Jpanels. I will then be adding more code into this that can then be used to do things inside these JPanels like adding buttons etc. Is this possible?

```
ArrayList<String> ClientArray = new ArrayList<String>();


public Application(){

    ClientArray.add("ShopA");
    ClientArray.add("ShopB");


    int arrayLength = ClientArray.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        JPanel Row.get(i) = new JPanel();
        Title = new JLabel(ClientArray.get(i));
        MainScreen.add(Row.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect `JPanel Row.get(i) = new JPanel();` to do?

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) *"Is this possible?"* Yes, but not by throwing random code statements together. The programmer needs to **understand** what each part of each code line is doing!

Comment: How about using a `JTable`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: @d.j.brown I wanted it to create a new rowpanel for each item in the Arraylist. So it would end up being Row1, Row2 etc